# Node : Cannot pass mongodb id equality check

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I know it sounds dumb but I really wonder what is it that I am missing here?

**Error:** It's not successfully checking for Mongodb's id equality rather throwing NotAuthorizedError.

**Code:**

```js
router.post('/:id', currentUser, authenticate, async (
    req: Request, res: Response
) => {

    const id = req.params.id
    const project = await Project.findById(id)
    if (!project) throw new NotFoundError()

    console.log(`CURRENT USER "${req.currentUser!.id}" AND PROJECT OWNER "${project.user}"`)
// OUTPUT : 
//CURRENT USER "5f499321ecae75127075ebae" AND PROJECT OWNER "5f499321ecae75127075ebae"

    if (project.user !== req.currentUser!.id) throw new NotAuthorizedError()
    await project.remove()
    res.status(201).send({})
})
```

*It is supposed to be equal as clearly logged in the console as well*

Comment: My guess is that you are comparing a string with a wrapper implementing a custom toString, hence testing the string against a reference. Did you try comparing to `project.user.toString()` ?

Comment: That's was it. Thanks, idk I never really faced that issue in the past. I wonder what I did different.

Comment: @36ve post this as an answer that the OP can accept :)

Comment: Your right thanks @eol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are comparing a string with a wrapper implementing a custom toString, hence testing the string against a reference. Did you try comparing to `project.user.toString()` ?

Comment: I saved the user type as mongoose.types.schema.objectId, that is why I need to change it to string